Is clickjacking still possible with maintaining session? Chrome updated same site cookies in 2020 to be more secure
I am learning about clickjacking, but I could not find any test website which - when being in an iframe - would maintain the session from the original "tab" if the user is logged in there.
I found this:
https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure
Is the traditional clickjacking (with session maintaining) impossible in the most modern browsers nowadays?

Is it still possible? Yes.  Is it much more difficult to do?  Yes.  Most browsers have been updated to mostly deal with this by default.   But if the true question is about security, don't use files on the remote user's pc to store data "cookies",  in a world where your server could host that data in a secure database.

@easleyfixed how does But if the true question is about security, don't use files on the remote user's pc to store data "cookies", in a world where your server could host that data in a secure database. related to clickjacking?

Simple.  In the title where it says " be more secure", as in this whole question is about security.   And being that a database is actual security versus trusting files on a remote computer.

Don't have time for a full answer: Most modern browsers set Lax as default for SameSite (except - imho - WebKit based browsers). So if a site relies on that default behavior and does not set the SameSite policy then it still might be vulnerable. Besides that sites still can be vulnerable if they use they use GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests to trigger some actions (which is a bad idea anyways).

And all that being said, that is why I prefer method POST .. the address bar is just an infintately long text field otherwise.  But @t.niese brings up some good points I agree with there.

@easleyfixed But it is still not clear what you want to say. Clickjacking is about a malicious site tricking a user into performing an action on a genuine site, mainly by loading this site in a transparent iframe, placed in such a way that the user thinks the click will happen on a UI element on the malicious site, but it actually happens a the genuine one (abusing that the session cookie of the genuine site is still submitted). How is a secure database related to that? The genuine site still needs a way to check if the user is authenticated, which is through cookies.

The point I am making is the site that requires a cookie to be used, if built to use a database for the users instead, is much more secure and thus that type of exploit wouldn't even be possible, the penultimate solution imho.  But as far as dealing with that issue directly, you probably need to get with cloudflare to see if they have a suggestion.
